# Creating multi-dimensional STL vector in class

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a class, I have a

`std::vector <std::vector<cell> > table;`

object.

The constructor takes an x and a y int and I want to create a table, that's size is x and y, and it contains cell object, constructed with its default constructor.

```
player(int x=10, int y=10, int length=5)
    {

        make_fleet(5);
        table_x=x;
        table_y=y;
        table=(y, std::vector<cell>(x));

    };
```

This is how the constructor looks like. The table object is private, that's it.

Sorry, this is one of my first posts but I would really appreciate some help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
player(int x=10, int y=10, int length=5)
    {

        make_fleet(5);
        table_x=x;
        table_y=y;

        table.resize(y);

        for (int i = 0; i < y; i++) {
            table[i].resize(x);
        }

    };
```